# Quickbooks Online connect to specific company

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I have an account associated to a merchant account. I would like to select a specific company then my app, but Quickbooks PHP DevKit doesn't give me this option. How could I be able to do it?

Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but Quickbooks PHP DevKit doesn't give me this option

Yes it does.

The responsibility of the DevKit (or really any other code that lives outside of Intuit.com) is just to forward you to the OAuth flow on Intuit's website. Nothing more.

From there, *once you're on Intuit's website*, you'll be prompted *by Intuit's website* to choose the correct QuickBooks Online company.

If you're using a DEVELOPMENT/SANDBOX app, then you will *only be able to connect to a SANDBOX QuickBooks Online company until you go to production*.

Are you using a DEVELOPMENT/SANDBOX app (e.g. are you using your development tokens, or production ones?)

Is the QuickBooks Online company you're trying to connect to a SANDBOX/DEVELOPMENT QuickBooks Online account, or a production one?

Comment: Thanks Keith, with your explaination I've resolved the problem! I was using sandbox account with development app, I've switched to a production app with my roduction account linked to the specific company and it worked!